# JPA Id generation with no existing sequence

Tags: java, jpa

I've got an oracle database with some data (I didn't make it, just got it) and now i want to add new one using JPA Entity with auto generated ID. However when I use annotations like:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name="gen",sequenceName="hibernate_sequence",allocationSize =1)
@Id @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
```

it throws non unique values exeption for my primary key.
is there any way to automaticaly check current highest id value and set it as initial value for generator sequence, or solve this issue any other way?

Comment: Why don't you create your hibernate_sequence starting by the current highest id?

Comment: Yes.  Interesting question, but if you're only going to do this once, why bother automating it?

Comment: I have to automate it as this database is changed not only by my application but also by another one and i don't have acces to that one